# Proof that all isometries can be written under the form $Q(x)+v$

Tags: proof-explanation, isometry

I want to show that all $f \in Isom(\mathbb{R^n})$ can be written as $f(x) = Q(x) +v$ with $Q \in o(n) $ and $v \in \mathbb{R^n}$

This is how the proof goes: Let us set G(x) = f(x) -v

We want to show 2 things:

- **G is linear**
- **G is orthogonal**

I get that it is necessary to show that G is orthogonal but why to we have to show G's linearity?

Comment: What would because an orthogonal application must be linear.

Comment: I suspect that proving it's linear is fairly easy, but that that linearity is thereafter useful in proving orthogonality. It's giving a hint about an easy way to proceed (or, if introducing a proof that's already written, setting up expectations about what you'll be shortly reading).

Comment: @JohnHughes No they don't use the fact that its linear to prove that G is orthogonal

Comment: @Surb Thank you! But if we show that it is orthogonal and if orthogonal application is linear, why do we first show linearity

Answer (score 1):

The proof follows quickly from a "crucial" lemma, namely the following:

*Lemma* let $G$ be an isometry fixing the origin, i.e., with $G(0)=0$. Then $G$ is a linear, orthogonal map.

Proof: Using the so-called polarization formula one obtains
\begin{equation}
  \begin{aligned}
2\langle x,y\rangle & =||x||^2+||y||^2-||x-y||^2 \\
 &= ||G(x)||^2+||G(y)||^2-||G(x)-G(y)||^2 \\
 & = 2\langle G(x),G(y)\rangle .
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
To show that $G$ is a linear map, let $(e_1,\ldots ,e_n)$ be an orthonormal basis.
Then also $(G(e_1),\ldots ,G(e_n)$ is an orhonormal basis. For each $x$ we have
\begin{equation}
  \begin{aligned}
x & =\sum_{k=1}^n \langle x,e_k\rangle e_k, \\
f(x) & = \sum_{k=1}^n\langle G(x),G(e_k)\langle G(e_k) \\
 & =  \sum_{k=1}^n \langle x,e_k\rangle G(e_k).
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
This implies that
$$
G\left(\sum_{k=1}^nx_ke_k\right)=\sum_{k=1}^n x_kG(x_k),
$$
which says that $G$ is linear. Together we have that $G$ is a linear map which keeps invariant the scalar product, i.e., which is an element of the linear orthogonal group $O_n(\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: In my case G does not necessarily fix the origin I believe

Comment: It does, because we replace it by $G(x)=f(x)-v$ with $v=f(0)$. This is exactly what you wrote. So we have $G(0)=f(0)-f(0)=0$.

Comment: Oh true thanks for pointing that ou